# Not able to take Value for json in MVC 5 Application

Tags: c#, jquery, json, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public ActionResult DyGridData(string id, string sord, int page, int rows) {
    EmployeeContext context = new EmployeeContext();
    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;
    int totalRecords = context.Employees.Count();
    int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

    var employees = context.Employees.OrderBy(p=>p.EmployeeId).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

    var jsonData = new {
        total = totalPages,
        page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = ( from employee in employees
            select new   { i=employee.EmployeeId ,
                           cell = new string[]
               { employee.Name, employee.Age.ToString(),employee.Salary.ToString(),employee.Department,employee.City }
            }).ToArray()
    };

    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);         
}
```

**Here I identify that in cell if i apply .ToArray() i am getting Exception   And if not then not getting value of cell and got remaining Value .**

Exception  is  :

An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: Sorry Not in Cell in rows i apply .toarray()

Comment: Just guessing but sounds like a problem with your EntityFramework configuration. If you debug and try context.Employees.ToList() at the top of your method does it execute or throw an exception? If this throws an exception also, I'd start digging into EntityFramework configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to execute the query first by adding [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) at the end of the statement.

```
var employees = context.Employees
   .OrderBy(p=>p.EmployeeId)
   .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
   .Take(pageSize)
   .ToArray(); // Add this.
```